# Injecting custom services in DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have some small "providers" for some basic functionality we want to be able to mock, such as a IDateTimeProvider.

```
public interface IDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime UtcNow { get; }
}
```

Previously we injected this in our DbContext using the constructor, but now we want to use `AddDbContextPool<>` and thus can't we use constructor injection anymore.

How can I inject this kind of classes into our DbContext implementation?

I tried providing an alternative "InternalServiceProvider" but this resulted in an InvalidOperationException "Entity Framework services have not been added to the internal service provider. Either remove the call to 'UseInternalServiceProvider' so that Entity Framework will manage its own internal services, or use the method from your database provider to add the required services to the service provider (e.g. 'AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer')."

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<TDbContext>(SetupDbContextOptions);

void SetupDbContextOptions(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

    IConfiguration? configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
    string connectionString = BuildConnectionString(configuration, databaseName);
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
}
```

I tried to find a way to access the `RootProvider` of the internal service provider of EF6; using the debugger I can see my service in there; but I could find a way to access it.

We are using EF6 in .Net 6.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the debugger in your posting.